# VAR(1) with DLM package Maximum Likelihood estimation

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a VAR(1) in DLM form, and I'm using this code:

y is a 200x3 matrix

```
build <- function(u) {dlm(m0=c(y[1,]),
C0=1*diag(3),
FF=diag(3),V=diag(c(1e-3,1e-3,1e-3)), 
GG= matrix(c(u[1:9]), ncol=3), 
W=matrix(c (exp(u[10]),u[11],u[12],u[11], exp(u[13]),u[14],u[12],u[14], exp(u[15]) ),ncol=3))}

init <- rep(0,15)
outMLE <- dlmMLE(y,init, build)
```

R can't calculate the dlmMLE and reports: "W is not a valid variance matrix".

I would appreciate any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Would you please show the value of p, the dimension of y, and the values in init? It might be that W fails to be positive definite.

Comment: p=3 and y is a 200x3 matrix. The initial values are all zeros.

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon your question, and haven't parsed the code too carfully... so forgive me if I missed the point...

but just looking at your construction of the variance matrix, it may not be suitably constrained. For example, the following respects your W construction, but doesn't work as a cov matrix:
matrix(c(1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1),3,3). (Try to compute the correlation matrix!) A more standard approach is to parameterize the covariance matrix via a Cholesky decomposition. For any 6 parameters, say a1-a6, let

W_ = matrix(c(a1,a2,a3,0,a4,a5,0,0,a6),3,3)  # arbitrary lower triangular matrix, then...
W = W_ %*% t(W_)

perhaps that helps.

drew

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem. Here is what I get. Best, ft.

```
> library(dlm)
> set.seed(12345)
> p <- 3
> y <- matrix(rnorm(600),ncol=3)
> build <- function(u) {dlm(m0=c(y[1,]),
+ C0=1*diag(3),
+ FF=diag(3),V=diag(c(1e-3,1e-3,1e-3)),
+ GG= matrix(c(u[1:9]), ncol=3),
+ W=matrix(c (exp(u[10]),u[11],u[12],u[11], exp(u[13]),u[14],u[12],u[14], exp(u[15]) ),ncol=3))}
> init <- rep(0,15)
> outMLE <- dlmMLE(y,init, build)
> outMLE
$par
 [1]  0.009390099  0.012975013  0.016513477 -0.086087006 -0.034091979
 [6]  0.005505462  0.022439820 -0.042064248  0.111033064  0.134691617
[11]  0.048333708  0.055505701 -0.086836031  0.069454628 -0.035391634

$value
[1] 300.5475

$counts
function gradient 
      10       10 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

Answer (score 0):

The same problem here: "is not a valid variance matrix". The solution provided above, namely writing as an arbitrary lower triangular solved my problem. As example:

```
M = matrix(c(exp(x[(m+1)]),x[(m+4)],x[(m+5)],0,exp(x[(m+2)]),x[(m+6)],0,0,exp(x[(m+3)])),3,3)
W(model) = M %*% t(M)
```